# Google's flan-t5 models are not loading on HuggingFaceHub through Langchain

Tags: google-colaboratory, langchain, huggingface-hub

I am trying to replicate the example code provided on Langchain website ([link here](https://python.langchain.com/en/latest/modules/models/llms/integrations/huggingface_hub.html)) but I am getting the following error whether I run it on Google colab or locally:

**HfHubHTTPError: 504 Server Error: Gateway Time-out for url: https://huggingface.co/api/models/google/flan-t5-xl**

The full code from the website is as follows:

```
!pip install huggingface_hub > /dev/null
# get a token: https://huggingface.co/docs/api-inference/quicktour#get-your-api-token

from getpass import getpass

HUGGINGFACEHUB_API_TOKEN = getpass()
import os
os.environ["HUGGINGFACEHUB_API_TOKEN"] = HUGGINGFACEHUB_API_TOKEN
from langchain import HuggingFaceHub

repo_id = "google/flan-t5-xl" # See https://huggingface.co/models?pipeline_tag=text-generation&sort=downloads for some other options

llm = HuggingFaceHub(repo_id=repo_id, model_kwargs={"temperature":0, "max_length":64})
```

the last line is where I am getting the error

```
llm = HuggingFaceHub(repo_id=repo_id, model_kwargs={"temperature":0, "max_length":64})
```

I tried it on Google Colab as well as local machine and it throws the same error. I tried hitting the URL https://huggingface.co/api/models/google/flan-t5-xl through a browser and got the same error.

Comment: This issue is being tracked [here](https://github.com/hwchase17/langchain/issues/3275) - current workaround with most upvotes is to set `temperature > 0`

Answer (score 2):

Use the following model: "google/flan-t5-xxl"